# add customView to NSStatusItem

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I would like to create a status bar application which has non-menu style. same as FaceTab for facebook (I mean only interface, not functional)... this is my codes:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];
    [statusItem setView:customView];
    //[statusItem setMenu:menu];
    [statusItem setTitle:@"Status"];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
}
```

.....
so once I Use NSMenu everything works fine but when I use NSView and CustomView outlet nothing appear on menu bar. Help plz!

Comment: Are you sure customView draws something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several moving parts involved, so the best advice I can give is to check out this excellent [example project](http://blog.shpakovski.com/2011/07/cocoa-popup-window-in-status-bar.html) from Vadim Shpakovski.

Comment: Can you suggest me a simpler way , I just want to link a custom view and makes it appear once I click on my app icon on Status Bar.

Comment: You can't attach a view to a Status Item -- you have to attach a NSMenu to it, then add your custom view to a NSMenuItem within that menu.  You'll run into all sorts of problems if you want to do any event handling, though. I strongly recommend you use a proper NSWindow like in the example I linked to.

Comment: Yes, Thats what I wanted, Thanks :), for those who as same problem :
you just need to right-click on any item in NSMenu (in .xib file) then link "View" to your control (such as custom View or button or anything else).

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your awakeFromNib method, you may need to call retain on the statusItem so that it doesn't go out of scope. I was struggling with this same problem, and adding `[statusItem retain];` fixed it so that I now see my Status menu in the Mac OS status bar.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];
    [statusItem setView:customView];

    // in my code, this is uncommented, and menu is an instance variable.
    //[statusItem setMenu:menu];

    [statusItem setTitle:@"Status"];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];

    // this was needed to get the icon to display in the status bar.
    [statusItem retain];
}
```